# sns.countplot - 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'countplot''

Tags: python, plot, count, seaborn

I am trying to create a countplot with sns. I adapted the following code:

```
sns.countplot(x="deck", data=titanic, palette="Greens_d")
```

I use a data frame called dfvp where XP is a categorical variable which can take two string values (either defense or prosecution).

here is my adapted code:

```
sns.countplot(x="XP", data=dfvp, palette="Greens_d")
```

Here is the error message that I get:

```
sns.countplot(x="XP", data=dfvp, palette="Greens_d")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-220-20d65ae5d282>", line 1, in <module>
sns.countplot(x="XP", data=dfvp, palette="Greens_d")

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'countplot'
```

FYI: I use ANACONDA and Python 3.4. on a PC with Windows 8.

Could you tell me how to fix this/what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

Here is a MCVE

```
import seaborn as sns 
dfvp = read_csv('C:\\Users\\VP_Prod_study_2_data changed_3.csv')
sns.countplot(x="XP", data=dfvp, palette="Greens_d")
```

Comment: Can you post the exact code you are running? For instance:  

    ```import seaborn as sns``` 
    ```sns.countplot() ```

Comment: In the question i see 2 times `sns.countplot` and one time (in the exception) `ns.countplot`. Is there a typo?

Comment: My guess would be an older version of seaborn that doesn't have the `countplot` function.

Comment: sorry, yes there is a typo, should show sns.countplot.

Comment: @Johnchase: I manage to run other plots based on the data frame and using seaborn (e.g., violinplot).
Here is the exact code: 
`import seaborn as sns`  

`dfvp = read_csv('C:\\Users\\VP_Prod_study_2_data changed_3.csv'). `

`sns.countplot(x="XP", data=dfvp, palette="Greens_d")`

Comment: As noted previously, you may have an older version of seaborn. You can find that out by running `sns.__version__` I'm not sure what version countplots was added, though if you are not running 0.6.0 you should upgrade and try running the code again.

Comment: I had this error. Caused by naming my own testing file seaborn.py